# Code first mapping in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first, foreign-key-relationship

I have created 3 tables using Code First Approach. I get the following Model Validation Exception when i execute a Find on student table.

> Student_courses_Target_Student_courses_Source: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.

```
public class University
{
    [Key]
    public string Uni_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Course> Courses { get; set; } 
}

 public class Course
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Course_ID { get; set; }


    [Key,ForeignKey("uni")]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Uni_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public virtual University uni { get; set; }
}

    public class Student
{
    [Key,ForeignKey("course"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Course_ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("course"),Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Uni_ID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public string Student_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Course course { get; set; }
}
```

By my understanding , the exception means that i have not mapped my foreign keys in student table to the primary keys in course table. But i have done it . Is there an issue as to how the 'Uni_ID' occurs as Primary key in both University and Course Tables and perhaps i have gone wrong in referencing it as foreign key in the Student table ?

Comment: What is the `[Column(Order=3)]` on the Student_ID referring to?

Comment: @Eris Nothing. Its just a normal property and a primary key.